# Generar un regex dinámicante con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Supongamos este escenario

```
var1 = "|".join({"var1.1", "var1.2"})
var2 = "|".join({"var2.1", "var2.2"})
```

Y luego la expresión regex:

```
regex = r"^(?!.*(?:var1.1|var1.2|var2.1|var2.2)\b).*$"
```

Lo que intento hacer es algo de este estilo

```
fullExpresion = "|".join({var1, var2})
regex = r"^(?!.*(?:"+fullExpression+")\b).*$"
```

Al hacerle un print a regex me imprime bien lo que supuestamente quiero que se genere, pero después si paso valores a ese nuevo regex, no funciona como espero y si le paso "var1.2" no lo bloquea

Qué estoy obviando?

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ¿Cómo lo estas probando? Por favor agrega el ejemplo completo

Comment: Prueba con `regex = rf"^(?!.*(?:{fullExpresion})\b).*$"`

Comment: @christian yo no usaria f-strings para crear dinamicamente regex. Esto por que las llaves significan cosas en las regex, y habria que escaparlas es esos casos.

Comment: @DanteS. cierto, entonces convendría usar `.format()`? Estoy redactando una respuesta pero quiero ver si el uso de `.format()` quedaría como mejor solución a usar `f-strings` .

Comment: Format utiliza llaves tambien. La mejor solucion es la que propuse en el comentario a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un pequeño error que pasa desapercibido. Cuando crear la cadena de forma dinámica estas concatenando los strings, pero solo al primer string le antepones la `r` (indicando que será un `raw string`). El problema ocurre al concatenar el último string, dado que no le antepones la `r` python lo scapará el `\b`.

La solución sería que le antepongas la `r` a todo string que concatenes

```py
regex = r"^(?!.*(?:" + fullExpression + r")\b).*$"
```

Como propuse en mi comentario también podemos usar `f-string` para hacer esto

```py
regex = rf"^(?!.*(?:{fullExpresion})\b).*$"
```

Sin embargo, al declararlo también como `f-string` tendríamos que escapar los caracteres `{}` en caso queramos usarlos como parte de la expresión regular y esto no se resuelve usando `\` (ya que los `f-string` no los soporta), tendríamos que hacer `{{}}` para que se tome como literal.

Por ahora la mejor solución a mi parecer es la primera opción, la de no olvidarse de colocar la `r` en cada concatenación. Estaré actualizando la publicación si encuentro otras formas.

Comment: Tambien puedes usar un metodo de la vieja escuela (lo uso en regex y el snbt de Minecraft): %s

Comment: Bien, en un rato la agrego, gracias.